# cpulimit does not detect Node.JS process

Tags: process, limit, node.js

I was able to limit python process to use only 50% CPU with the following

`cpulimit -l 50 -e python`

but when I tried to do the same for Node, and it is not able to detect the process at all. Does anyone know? In the `ps aux`, I can see `node`, so I am not sure what is missing

`cpulimit -l 50 -e node`

The platform I am running on is Ubuntu 14.04, but I'd imagine this issue should be linux flavor agnostic.

My current work around is

`cpulimit -l 50 -p $(pidof node)`

However, it means that it does not detect any new instances of node processes.

Comment: cpulimit looks at the file path referenced by the symlink /proc/nnn/exe. On your system, is "node" part of the name?

Comment: I am no expert in the unix system, but no, I do not see `node` under `/proc` But then again, I don't see `python` under `/proc` either, and yet, `cpulimit` doesn't seem to have trouble limiting the CPU usage. I should add that ubuntu doesn't have `/proc/nnn/exe` and I assume you only used that as an example

Comment: Sorry, yes, replace `nnn` with the numeric process id of the node process. What is the output of `ls -l "/proc/$(pidof node)/exe"` ?

Answer (score 2):

`cpulimit` is known not to work well in some cases. Sometimes it works quite well (on simple single threaded apps) and other times (mostly mutli-threaded or muti-process) it doesn't work.

Technically speaking, there are two issues that could cause cpulimit to not limit. First is that the program your trying to run spawns a thread or process in such a way that the spawned thread is not a child of spawning thread. There are several reasons to do this, but it is a bit uncommon.

Second is the fact that SIGSTOP is not a signal that can be "handled". But signals are asynchronous. So Thread a can spawn thread b. thread a can be SIGSTOP'ed while thread b is launching, and thread b launches without the signal.

Also SIGSTOP pauses a process "when it can". There are times, specially with disk io that a thread would not be pausable. The most common of those that I can think of is disk IO.

In other words while SIGSTOP (what cpulimit uses) should stop a thread and all other child threads, it does not always do it in the way you expect in complex multi-threaded apps that can launch other processes. You would be better served by using traditional scheduling throttling (nice) in these cases.

Comment: Really open to comments on this answer. There are a lot of conflicting docs on SIGSTOP out there. SIGSTOP can not usually be handled or caught. At the same time I know that a process that is SIGSTOPped can continue with IO.

Answer (score 2):

With the comment from @Mark Plotnick, I finally figured out the reason

`ls -l "/proc/$(pidof node)/exe"` returns

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 antony antony 0 Aug 27 13:04 /proc/4414/exe -> /usr/bin/nodejs`

So instead of `node`, I should have used `nodejs`

The following command works

`cpulimit -l 50 -e nodejs`

Update: this is actually not a bullet-proof solution. Yes, `cpulimit` can detect the `nodejs` process, but if you are running a persistent `nodejs` script, `cpulimit` can prematurely cause `nodejs` script to terminate without any warning

Update2: It would appear on the console/terminal that nodejs process stopped, but in reality, nodejs is still running in the background.